# 'Convert' 5 chars to int

Tags: c++

I have a 5 char string `ad3s5`, `sdgsd`, etc containing only small letters and numbers.

So, we have 5 chars and 36 possible values for each char. This means there are `5^36` unique numbers able to represent this.

How to convert the 5 chars to a unique number in the range `0-5^36`?

Comment: So you're basically looking to parse Base36 in C++?

Comment: Not sure but seems like you got it correct

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36

Comment: Okay thank you all i think i will solve it now!!

Comment: `5^36` is about 788860 times bigger than a 64 bit int. You can't create a _perfect hash code_, which is what you're trying to do, FYI.

Comment: Sorry i meant 36^5, you are right though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) to decode base 36 like this:

```
unsigned long val = std::strtoul(str, nullptr, 36);
```

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    const char* str = "zzzzz";
    unsigned long val = std::strtoul(str, nullptr, 36);
    std::cout << val;
}
```

outputs `60466175` which is 36<sup>5</sup>-1.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) from the standard library and specify `base = 36`

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::strtol("ad3s5", NULL, 36) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::strtol("sdgsd", NULL, 36) << '\n';
}
```

See it run [here at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/C6Owcm)